# Marking out points on surface directly above level curve in xy-plane

Tags: python, math, plot, projection, surface

I have a 3D plot with a surface z = f(x,y) and a level curve g(x,y) = c. This last one lies in the xy-plane. I need to somehow mark out the points on the surface which lie directly above the level curve. I am trying to maximize f, but are restricted to the points directly above g(x,y)=c. Therefore, for illustrational purposes, it would be nice to make it clear for my readers which points we are evaluating. My current plot looks like this:
[Current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXkGt.png)

My first idea was to somehow collect the points on g(x,y) = c, adding them to a list, and then again plot z = f(x,y) with these points as the argument. Is that overcomplicating things?
I know that Python has commands for projecting from surfaces to the xy-plane. What I am trying here is kinda the other way around. Does Python have a command for that?
Answers are highly appreciated.